# Switch statement goes directly to default even with breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

What I'm attempting to do is to create a switch statement that takes data from the JSON API and prints it depending on the location of the user.

For example, if the user is located in the US, then it prints only the city and state. If located outside of the US, it prints the city and the country. If the city is an empty string, then it prints only the country.

As of now, no matter what location I set my VPN to, it goes to the default case(city and country).

```
  var location;
  var city;
  var state;
  var country;

  $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    location = data.loc;
    city = data.city;
    state = data.region;
    country = data.country;

    switch (data) {
      case country === 'US':
        $("#yourCity").html(city + ", " + state);
        break;
      case city === "":
        $("#yourCity").html(country);
        break;
      default:
        $("#yourCity").html(city + ", " + country);
    }
```

I chose to use a switch statement rather than an if statement because I may want to add more cases later on down the line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Pass the value to compare to `switch()` and use the possible values as `case`s. Ex: `switch(city) { case 'NY': codeHere; break; case 'NJ': codeHere; break; default: codeHere; }`

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass something more specific than just `data` in your switch statement. Since `data` is an object and not `country` or `city` it goes straight to the default.

I think you are thinking that when it goes through the case it looks through the object and sees if it has the value country or city, but it doesn't. You need to pass something like `switch(data.location)` and then data.location value is either country or city. So you might need to move things around a bit. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I assigned `data.country` to the variable `country` and passed `switch(country)` and nothing's changed. Did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: So when you pass something in switch(/*HERE*/) the value of that item is checked in case. Since you originally passed data - what is the value of data? Its unclear so you need to be more specific. You will need to rewire the structure of your data or rethink the cases. If you pass data.country your case should say `case  'US'` . You're asking the switch statement to check more than it can.

Answer (score 1):

Switch-case statement can be used only to compare one value with several others. According to your code sample, you have tried compare both country and city using switch case. That is not possible, definitely you'll have to use if-else statement handle this.

Please consider following method.

```
  var location;
  var city;
  var state;
  var country;

  $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    location = data.loc;
    city = data.city;
    state = data.region;
    country = data.country;

    if(country === 'US'){
        $("#yourCity").html(city + ", " + state);
    }else{
        if(city===''){
            $("#yourCity").html(country);
        }else{
            $("#yourCity").html(city + ", " + country);
        }
    }
```

You also used switch case statement in a wrong way. Switch case statements doesn't have arithmetic compare symbols. Try switch case statement as follows.

```
var day = new Date().getDay();
switch (day) {
    case 4:
    case 5:
        text = "Soon it is Weekend";
        break; 
    case 0:
    case 6:
        text = "It is Weekend";
        break;
    default: 
        text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I originally coded it using an if statement but thought that a switch statement would work because there could have potentially been quite a few cases. But I didn't know you couldn't compare with a switch statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the switch case properly.

Basically, you need to pass a specific type of `data`. Currently, the `switch` variable is not a `country` nor a `city` hence it goes straight to the `default`.

**further reading:**

[**JavaScript Switch Statement**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)